# Batch file to run multiple files matching certain pattern

Tags: batch-file

I have some python files in a directory, i created below batch file with logic to run multiple files which match certain pattern.

"path/to/python/exe" "C:/users/test/R1*.py"

I used * as a regex to match all files starting with R1, but this is not working

Comment: `FOR %%G IN ("C:\users\test\R1*.py") DO py.exe "%%G"`

Comment: The `*`-symbol is not a regular expression but a [wildcard](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.com)…